# Comparing cobar constructions for different types of (co)operads (e.g. cyclic vs. non-cyclic)

Tags: homological-algebra, operads

I am trying to understand a remark made by Clément Dupont and Bruno Vallete in their preprint "[Brown's moduli spaces of curves and the gravity operad](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.08840)" in the proof of Proposition 1.16:

They say (in particular) that for a nonsymmetric cyclic cooperad $\mathcal{P}$, the nonsymmetric cyclic cobar construction of $\mathcal{P}$ and the nonsymmetric cobar construction of (the nonsymmetric cooperad underlying) $\mathcal{P}$ have the same underlying chain complex. Since these two cobar constructions are built using sums over different types of trees, I don't see how this should work. (They refer to Remark 1.9 for this statement, but that remark is not related to the cobar construction.)

In general, I would be happy if someone could provide an insight on the relationship between cobar constructions of different types of (co)operads.